# Design - Sometimes an Object is-a and sometimes it isn't

Tags: uml

I realize the subject isn't very clear so I'll try to explain.
I'm trying to design a system for version control.
There are 3 types of users: simple user, owner and operator.
An operator is by no way a simple user/owner, but, he can run the system in special mode which will allow him to act as a simple user or owner for testing the correctness of the system.

The question: How would you describe the relationship (UML) between the system operator and the simple user/owner ?
I've been pondering a simple inheritance relationship, but my co-workers disagreee..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also disagree with you, user/owner/admin, are just the same object with different rights. So you should associate your user with rights attributes.
Of course using inheritance is possible, but not adequate. There is nothing different in the meaning of the user/superuser/admin, they are all for example a person.
You can change a user to a superuser  to an admin and vise versa, that's why i would not use inheritance here.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirement for user to impersonate owner or user.

I think I'd try

a user entity  Name , Password Type etc to manage the common stuff like log in.

Then three entities Operator, Owner and User which have a user.

There might (probably will be) more stuff you can make common, but I'd definitely go with Has a rather than is a.

I'd be tempted to do that even without the impersonate requirement, as inheritance would suggest that say owner could do everything that user could do and operator everything that owner could do, which is unlikely to be true.